# How to improve efficiency when classifying lists according to certain laws

Tags: performance-tuning

I have a function that generates lists:

```
f[n_] := Join @@ Permutations /@ PadLeft@IntegerPartitions[n];
```

For example

```
f[3]
```

> ```
> {{0, 0, 3}, {0, 3, 0}, {3, 0, 0}, {0, 2, 1}, {0, 1, 2}, 
>  {2, 0, 1}, {2, 1, 0}, {1, 0, 2}, {1, 2, 0}, {1, 1, 1}}
> ```

The result of `f[3]` is 10 lists of three elements, which I want to classify according to certain laws.

The lists `{0, 0, 3}`, `{0, 3, 0}` and `{3, 0, 0}` belong one class with 3 members because `RotateLeft` can transform any one of these into any of the others.

Similarly, `{0,1,2}`, `{1,2,0}` and `{2,0,1}` belong to one class with 3 members, `{0, 2, 1}`, `{2, 1, 0}` and `{1, 0, 2}` belong to one class with 3 members and `{1, 1, 1}` belongs to a class of which it is the only member.

The result I want is

[image]

The following code generates the desired result.

```
m = AbsoluteTime[];
f[n_Integer] := Join @@ Permutations /@ PadLeft@IntegerPartitions[n];
f2[list_] := Module[{n = 1, m = 0},
  While[n <= Length[data1], 
   If[Or @@ (SameQ[data1[[n, 1]], #] & /@ 
       NestList[RotateLeft, list, Length[list] - 1]), data1[[n, 2]]++;
     m++; Break[]];
   n++];
  If[m == 0, AppendTo[data1, {list, 1}]]]
data1 = {{First@f[7], 1}};
f2 /@ Drop[f[7], 1];
Length[f[7]]
data1 // Length
AbsoluteTime[] - m
```

Unfortunately, the code is too slow. When `n = 7`, it takes about 11 seconds, but I want to work with `n` is the range from 14 to 20. How can I improve efficiency the efficiency of my code?

Comment: Notice, that there is unscoped `data1` in `f2` definition.

Comment: Hey Chenminqi, I just wanted to ask if my (rather long) answer was of any use to you. Nice to see you are still active on the site :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I believe I'm missing some basic function that can easily reproduce the `test` here. But that's a detail, the main thing is to use `Tally` with the second argument specification:

```
test[x_List] := Sort@Array[RotateLeft[x, #] &, Length[x]]

Tally[f[3], test[#1] == test[#2] &] // MatrixForm
```

> $\left(
> \begin{array}{cc}
>  \{0,0,3\} & 3 \\
>  \{0,2,1\} & 3 \\
>  \{0,1,2\} & 3 \\
>  \{1,1,1\} & 1 \\
> \end{array}
> \right)$

It's not the optimal way, for `n = 10` it takes about 5 sec on my old pc. I will think about improvements.

Comment: @user10193 Please hold on with an accept a little, it is a good habit in order to not discourage others. I'm 100% sure that better answers will appear here. :)

Comment: Tkx very much.I considered about tally but I just know use Tally[list] but Tally[list, test].so thank you.

Comment: @Kuba do you mean `First@Sort` in test? Now you end up comparing lists of lists, whereas you only need to compare one representative. I agree there should probably be some trick to do this step :)

Comment: @JacobAkkerboom No I didn't, but good idea with `First` it may help with long lists. I was thinking about something like built in testing if two lists are related with an odd/even permutation. But I must admit my math skils are not existant in this area. I don't even know if what I'm thinking about is called even permutation in english :). I was trying to avoid  to many `Sort`ing with `MemberQ[test[#],#2]&` as the second argument but it seems it is longer.

Comment: @Kuba it is an interesting problem. Odd/even permutations are a big thing, so its probably the right word ;). If you can tackle it like that I'd be curious. For me the main problem becomes finding that the "lowest subsequence" of length 3 of `{0,1,2,0,0,3}` is `{0,0,3}` and not `{0,1,2}`. Hrm :P

Comment: Hmm I've made some code to find a unique representation (essentially the same one found by the composition of `First` and `Sort`), but really it is silly for this case with much duplicate elements. I suppose it would be quite fast in C.. Oh well still I encourage you to write First@Sort@... :)

Comment: Ahh you are very right. This should be solved with group theory. Aiai :P

Comment: @JacobAkkerboom well, of course I am :P. So, have you found anything built-in? p.s. I must say I like you digging style but your codes are usualy exactly the oposit to the reason I love MMA :p, I mean, I have not parsed it yet, but I will! :)

Answer (score 5):

*The theory bit feels a bit clumsy and there is an off by one error somewhere in the theory (not in the code)*.

**Introduction**

The key to concept to tackling this problem is rotational symmetry. Using this, it turns out that we can find out how many elements your classes have relatively easily (in terms of memory and CPU usage, it does take some math). Actually finding and storing the elements that represent the classes is more of a programming challenge than a mathematical one, and this is what will cost most computational resources. The algorithm I present finds exactly one representative of each class, so in this way the problem is nicely cut into two parts.

**Theory**

Now let's do some group theory. Throughout the text of this answer, let $n$ be the `n` of your question, which is the integer for which we want to describe such classes. In my code I will call this variable `in` for input. It turns out the classes you describe are [orbits](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Group_action#Orbits_and_stabilizers) of the group $\mathbb{Z}_n$ acting on the set of [weak compositions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Composition_(combinatorics)) of $n$. Let's give the set of weak compositions a name

$$X_n = \lbrace \vec x \in (\mathbb{Z}_n)^n | \sum_{k=1}^n x_k = n \rbrace$$

We wish to know how many elements there are in any particular class a.k.a. orbit. The section on wikipedia article that explains about orbits gives a result that we can use here, in its subsection [Orbit-stabilizer theorem and Burnside's lemma](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Group_action#Orbit-stabilizer_theorem_and_Burnside.27s_lemma). The result states

$$|G.x| = |G|\; /\; |G_x|$$

On the LHS is the quantity we are after, i.e. the number of elements of the orbit of $x$. Formally, $G_x$ is called the stabiliser of x, a notion which is also explained in the article. However, we can forget about stabilisers and look directly at $|G_x|$. $|G_x|$ is the number of elements of $G$ for which $g.x =x$. For our group $G = \mathbb{Z}_n$ this is something quite intuitive. For example for $n = 6$ and

$$x=(1,1,1,1,1,1)$$

we see that all elements of $G$ map x to x. So $|G_x| = n = 6$. So for this particular $x$, $|G.x| = |G|\; /\; |G_x| = n/n = 1$. Of course it was quite clear that the class to which $x$ belongs has only one element. Now consider

$$x=(0,0,3,0,0,3)$$

the class to which this $x$ belongs has 3 elements, because there are 2 ways we can left shift this onto itself. We can shift by 0 or 3 spots. So in this case $|G.x| = 6/2 = 3$. In this last example let us say that $x$ has period 3, because the smallest repeating subsequence that comprises $x$ is $(0,0,3)$ which has length 3. It should be clear that if we know the period of a sequence $x$, it is easy to find the length of its orbit.

There is another advantage to considering the periods of sequences. We can partition  the set of orbits by their periods. Then finding all the classes of which the elements have a certain period can be transformed into the original problem. If for $n = 6$, we wish to find all sequences with period 3, we simply have to solve the same problem for $n = 3$. That is, for $n=3$ we have the sequences

$$ (1,1,1)\quad (0,1,2) \quad (0,2,1)\quad (0,0,3)$$

and so for $n=6$ we have the corresponding sequences

$$ (1,1,1,1,1,1)\quad (0,1,2,0,1,2) \quad (0,2,1,0,1,2)\quad (0,0,3,0,0,3)$$

But both sequences that consist only of 1's have period 1 and not 3. So in the case for $n=3$, we have to consider the trivial subproblem for $n=1$. To get a proper one-to-one correspondence between such sequences, we should only consider the aperiodic elements in the subproblems. Here, by aperiodic I mean that an element of $x \in X_n$ is aperiodic if the period of $x$ is $n$.

One last nice bit of theory is the following. We can also derive how many orbits there are. It is nice to know how many orbits there will be, as this will tell us how long our arrays will have to be. We will first only consider the case where $n$ is prime, which will lead to a useful result when we work with aperiodic sequences. For $n$ prime, we can easily relate the number of orbits to $|X_n|$.  Let $Y_n$ be the set of orbits. As every orbit contains $n$ elements, as $n$ is prime, we have

$$|Y_n| = |X_n|\; /\; n $$

Now recall that $X_n$ is the set of [weak compositions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Composition_(combinatorics)) of $n$. In the section [Number of compositions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Composition_(combinatorics)#Number_of_compositions) of this wiki article, we find that the number of weak compositions is $\binom{2 n -1}{n -1}$ (use the formula with $k=n$). So we have

$$ |Y_n| = \binom{2 n -1}{n -1}\; /\; n $$

For $n$ which are not prime, partition $X_n$ by period and count the elements in each of the parts. Maybe now the following function explains itself. The idea is that in later code there will be a big array `main`, consisting of sequences of length $n$ (`in` in the code). In this array the elements are ordered by period. Maybe the first `f[1]` will have period $n$ and the elements `f[1]+1;;f[2]` will have period $n/2$. We have that `outSize` is the length of array `main` and that `subListLength` gives the length of the parts (`f[i_]:=subListLength[[i]]`).

```
ClearAll[mInitialization, divs, divDivisors, divLen, terms, bins, 
outSize]
mInitialization[in_] :=
  (
   divs = Divisors[in];

   divDivisors =
    Outer[If[# == #2, False, Divisible[#, #2]] &, divs, divs];

   divLen = Length@divs;

   terms = ConstantArray[0, divLen];

   bins = Binomial[2 # - 1, #] & /@ divs;

   Do[
    terms[[iter]] = 
     bins[[iter]] - 
      Sum[If[divDivisors[[iter, kkkk]], terms[[kkkk]], 0], {kkkk, 
        divLen}]

    ,
    {iter, divLen}

    ];

   subListLengths = Reverse[terms/divs];

   outSize = Total[subListLengths];

   );
```

**Compiled function**

I will not go into the details of finding the representations of the classes. There is a little bit more interesting math here and maybe I will post that later.

First let's make a tidy overview of our variables. The variables in `hConsts` are basically values that will inlined in the compiled function.

```
hConsts = Hold[walkedBack, walkedForward, maxDepth];
hLocals = 
  Hold[test, depth, direction, total, iters, (*activeGap,*) 
   distanceToGap, initVal, candidate, storage, storeCount];
ClearAll @@ hLocals;
ClearAll @@ hConsts;
walkedBack = 0;
walkedForward = 1;
maxDepth := in - 1
```

Here is the initialization of the compiled function we will use. It is not actually used as a function, but it is inlined, as it will be part of a compiled function.

```
(*OwnValues of initialization are used*)
initialization :=
 (
  iters = Table[0, {in - 1}];
  iters[[in - 1]] = in;
  total = 0;

  depth = maxDepth;

  test = True;

  (*activeGap=0;*)
  direction = walkedForward;
  distanceToGap = 0;

  storage = ConstantArray[0, {outSize, in}];

  storeCount = 0;
  )
```

Here is the code that is used to store a sequence in our array. This code is also inlined in the compiled function.

```
store[] := 
  (
   Increment[storeCount];
   Do[
    storage[[storeCount, kkkk + 1]] = iters[[kkkk]]
    ,
    {kkkk, in - 1}
    ];
   );
```

This is the main code of the compiled function.

```
codezzz :=
 (
  While[
   test
   ,
   If[
    depth < maxDepth
    ,
    If[
     direction == walkedBack
     ,


     If[
      total + iters[[depth]] <= 
       in - 2 (*we know a sequence cannot end in a 0, 
      so we need space for at least a 1. This argument should be \
expanded.*)
      ,

      Increment[iters[[depth]]];
      total += iters[[depth]];
      Increment[depth];
      direction = walkedForward;
      (*activeGap=depth;*)
      distanceToGap = 0;

      (*after we have walked back, we always start with a 0, 
      unless depth \[Equal] maxDepth*)

      ,
      Decrement[depth];
      direction = walkedBack;
      (*as we added 1 before prematurely*)

      If[
       depth == 0
       ,
       test = False;
       ,
       total = total - iters[[depth]];
       ]
      ]

     ,
     (*if cont: walkedForward*)

     If[
      distanceToGap > 0,
      initVal = iters[[distanceToGap]],
      initVal = 0;
      ];


     If[
      total + initVal <= in - 1
      ,
      (*initialization*)
      iters[[depth]] = initVal;

      Increment[depth];
      direction = walkedForward;
      Increment[distanceToGap];
      total = total + initVal
      ,
      Decrement[depth];
      direction = walkedBack;
      total -= iters[[depth]]

      ]


     ]

    ,

    If[
     distanceToGap == 0,

     iters[[depth]] = in - total;
     store[]
     ,

     candidate = in - total;

     If[
      candidate > iters[[distanceToGap]]
      ,
      iters[[depth]] = candidate;
      store[]
      ]

     ];
    Decrement[depth];
    direction = walkedBack;
    (*activeGap=0;*)
    total -= iters[[depth]]

    ]

   ];
  storage
  )
```

This code creates the compiled function

```
cfu =
  ReleaseHold[
     Unevaluated[
      Compile[{{in, _Integer}, {outSize, _Integer}},
       Block[
        #1
        ,
        #2
        ]
       , CompilationTarget :> "C"
       ]
      ]
     ] & @@
   {
    List @@@ Hold[Evaluate[hLocals]]
    ,
    (
      (
        Hold[
          initialization;
          codezzz
          ] /. Join[OwnValues[codezzz], OwnValues[initialization]]
        ) /. Apply[Join, List @@ OwnValues /@ hConsts]
      ) /. DownValues[store]
    };
```

The compiled function finds only aperiodic sequences. We need more functions! This function handles cacheing, which is especially useful as we need to solve subproblems. The `W` in `cfuW` is for wrapper.

```
<<Developer`
cached[x_] := False;
ClearAll[cfuW];
cfuW[inSub_ /; inSub > 2, outSize_, isAperiodicSize_] :=

  If[isAperiodicSize,
   If[
    TrueQ@cached[inSub],
    cache[inSub],
    {
      cache[inSub] = cfu[inSub, outSize],
      cached[inSub] = True
      } // First
    ],
   cfu[inSub, outSize]
   ];
cfuW[1, 1, True] := {{1}} // ToPackedArray;
cfuW[2, 1, True] := {{0, 2}} // ToPackedArray;
```

Another wrapper to localize some variables in the aperiodic case

```
findAperiodicComps[inSub_] :=
 Block[
  {in, outSize, divs, terms, subListLengths},
  in = inSub;
  mInitialization[in]; 
  cfuW[in, Last[terms]/Last[divs], True]
  ]
```

Finally, the function that deals with the general case.

```
ClearAll[findComps]
findComps[inSub_] :=
 Block[
  {in, main, rest, spanLists, divs, terms, subListLengths}
  ,
  in = inSub;
  mInitialization[in]; (*sets outSize etc*)

  main = ConstantArray[0, {outSize, in}];
  main[[;; Last[terms]/Last[divs]]] = 
   cfuW[in, Last[terms]/Last[divs], True];
  rest =
   cfuW[#, #2, True] &
    @@@
    Reverse[
     Delete[
      Transpose[
       {
        divs,
        terms/divs
        }
       ]
      ,
      {{-1}}
      ]
     ];
  spanLists =
   Transpose[
    {1 + Delete[#, -1], Delete[#, 1]} &@
     Accumulate@Reverse[terms/divs]
    ];
  Function[
    main[[Span @@ #3]] = ArrayPad[
      #
      ,
      {0, {0, in - #2}}
      ,
      "Periodic"
      ]
    ] @@@
   Transpose[
    {rest, Reverse[Delete[divs, -1]], spanLists}

    ];
  {main, divs, subListLengths}
  ]
```

**Functions to conform to OPs format**

The format required by the OP forces the unpacking of arrays. But it is useful to show how get the data in this format.

```
take[result_, terms_, subListLengths_, a_ ;; b_] :=
 Transpose[
  {
   result[[a ;; b]]
   ,
   Flatten[
     ConstantArray[#, #2] & @@@ 
      Transpose[{Reverse@terms, subListLengths}], 1][[a ;; b]]
   }
  ]

take[result_, terms_, subListLengths_, All] :=
 Transpose[
  {
   result
   ,
   Flatten[
    ConstantArray[#, #2] & @@@ 
     Transpose[{Reverse@terms, subListLengths}], 1]
   }
  ]

takeSimple[in_] := take[##, All] & @@ findComps[in]
```

**Result**

We now have

```
takeSimple[3] // MatrixForm
```

[image]

Which has a different ordering than both the OPs code and Kuba's code, but sure enough is correct.

**Comparison set up**

```
f[n_]:=Join@@Permutations/@PadLeft@IntegerPartitions[n];
test[x_List]:=Sort@Array[RotateLeft[x,#]&,Length[x]]
representation[x_List] := 
 First@test[x];
kuba[n_]:=Tally[f[n],test[#1]==test[#2]&]
```

**Actual comparison**

```
n = 10;
(resKubaShort = kuba[n][[All, 1]]) // Timing // First
(resJacobShort = findComps[n][[1]]) // Timing // First
```

> ```
>  2.231080  
>  0.004269
> ```

```
SameQ @@ Sort /@ {representation /@ resKubaShort, resJacobShort}
```

> ```
> True
> ```

This also indicates that all the results in `resJacobShort` are canonical. For what its worth.

A timing for higher `n` would be

```
n = 15;
(resJacobShort = findComps[n][[1]]) // Timing // First
```

> ```
> 3.690403
> ```

I think it can still run it for `n=16`. But for higher `n`, we run out of memory. Memory usage in this code does not display much CS skill. We store integers that cannot be larger than `n` as 64 bit integers. No effort is made to for example store part of the list on the hard drive to load it on demand. Maybe someday..